# Unable to access req.user after deployment to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I am building a web application that requires its users to login and features are built using the passport.js req.user object. This has caused no problems when working on localhost; however, after deploying, the application has reported that req.user is "undefined".

I have reviewed the passport.js code and it is similar to past projects that have worked when deployed. I've seen another stackoverflow post with a similar problem but the solution was to ensure that this code was in the server.js file.

```
app.use(
  session({
   store: new redis({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL }),
    secret: process.env.REDIS_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }),
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I expected that I could grab the req.user object the same was as in localhost but in production I would receive the following error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":500,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://mylingual.me/api/decks","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://mylingual.me/api/decks: 500 OK","error":"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;id&#39; of undefined<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router.route.get (/app/server/routes/decks.js:21:32)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.handle (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:338:9)</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
```

Edit #1: Not sure if it would be an issue but my application is running in HTTPS as well.

Comment: Where is the code for `/app/server/routes/decks.js` ??